# iptables DROP does not silently drop the packets

Tags: postgresql, iptables

I have two servers, one acting as a standby and the other as active. From the standby pgpool constantly checking whether postgres is working on the other server. I am trying to simulate a situation where the pgpool's request to the active server times out, and trying to use iptables DROP for that.

According to what I have read, the DROP option silently drops packets without the source getting to know it and, it takes a long time to fail (for the source to know). I used the below entry in the iptables of the active server:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s <standby server ip> \
         -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED --dport 5432 -j DROP
```

By doing this, I could simulate a timeout but it times out too soon (not even a second).

Can anyone explain what does it mean by "take a long time to fail" in all the references? and whether there's any option that I can use to increase the time taken to fail.

Comment: Assuming an ipv4 linux client, check `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_syn_retries`. Typical value is `5` giving a `~60s` timeout.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I checked the values and it's there as you mentioned. However I found that the DROP is actually working but pgpool is not honoring the timeout

Comment: @spathirana _pgpool is not honoring the timeout_ — no no no... pgpool probably has its own timeout and it is smaller than what you expect. It's going to be used on an Intranet so the timeout can be 100ms and be much more than sufficient to know that the connection is not going to happen. Many clients work that way on the Internet backends to make sure requests are fulfilled quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested this again by using telnet instead of pgpool and it did wait for 60 seconds as expected. Turns out the issue is in pgpool itself but not in iptables. I am providing this as the answer for anyone who would come across this. Thanks all for the answers

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the location of the rule in your ruleset it may not be firing and the packets from `<standby server ip>` could be hitting an `ALLOW` rule.

You can actively monitor `iptables` to see what rules are firing by using `watch`

```
$ sudo watch -n1 "iptables -vnL"
```

"Take a long time to fail" means that `DROP` tells iptables to not respond to the packet's sender with a tcp reset packet or icmp error.  This causes the sender to have to wait for their specified timeout period before closing the attempted connection.

Comment: Thanks Creek, I know that it's hitting the DROP rule as I get the timeout in my active server (the source) as soon as I add the rule via a script. And starts accepting requests when I remove the rule again via a script. Perhaps I have to check the specified timeout period.